# Substitute Any() call of IDBSet/IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq, expression, iqueryable, nsubstitute

I´m trying to substitute the call `Any()` of an `IDBSet<T>` with NSubstitute but the test fails with an `ArgumentNullException`

> Test Name:    TestMethod1 Test
>   FullName: Clientmanagement.Tests.UnitTest1.TestMethod1
>   Test
>   Source:   c:\develop\Clientmanagement\Clientmanagement.Tests\UnitTest1.cs
>   : line 12 Test Outcome:   Failed Test Duration:   0:00:00.3701927
>
> Result Message:    Test method
>   Clientmanagement.Tests.UnitTest1.TestMethod1 threw
>   exception:  System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: arguments Result StackTrace:   at
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.RequiresCanRead(Expression
>   expression, String paramName)    at
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateOneArgument(MethodBase
>   method, ExpressionType nodeKind, Expression arg, ParameterInfo pi)
>   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateArgumentTypes(MethodBase
>   method, ExpressionType nodeKind, ReadOnlyCollection`1& arguments)
>
>   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(Expression instance,
>   MethodInfo method, IEnumerable`1 arguments)    at
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(Expression instance,
>   MethodInfo method, Expression[] arguments)    at
>   System.Linq.Queryable.Any[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1
>   predicate)    at
>   Clientmanagement.Tests.UnitTest1.TestMethod1() in
>   c:\develop\Clientmanagement\Clientmanagement.Tests\UnitTest1.cs:line
>   19

Here is how my Test method looks like

```
public void EnsureThatIdentifierIsUnique() {
  IClientContext context = Substitute.For<IClientContext>();

  IDbSet<Client> clients = Substitute.For<IDbSet<Client>>();

  context.Clients.Returns(clients);

  clients.Any(p=>p.Identifier == "Test").Returns(true);  // this line throws the exception

  ClientService service = new ClientService(context);

  service.CreateClient("Test");
}
```

Now my question is if it is possible to substitute the methods of `IQueryable` with NSubstitute? Is the setup of my test method wrong?

Comment: Mocking expression trees is *hard*, some of the frameworks flat out don't support it (I'm looking at you, `Moq`). Mocking static helper/extension methods is even harder (now I'm looking at you, `Dapper` ;) ). I'm not entirely sure how EF is faring on this field now, but what you're describing is why - when I'm using NHibernate - I'm swapping database to in-memory SQLite DB for unit tests where I can set up custom data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now my question is if it is possible to substitute the methods of IQueryable with NSubstitute?

`Any` isn't a method on `IQueryable`. It's an *extension* method - a static method which is called as if it were an instance method. So unless NSubstitute can mock out static methods somehow (like [Typemock Isolator](http://www.typemock.com/isolator-product-page) does), you're going to have problems.

A really smart LINQ-oriented mocking system *could* essentially provide fake information to `Queryable` and respond to similar expression trees when it was given them by the production code - but it would be *very* fragile. You'd be better off with an in-memory database if at all possible.

In general, you shouldn't rely on your production code making an *exact* sequence of calls if another sequence would be equivalent. For example, it would be *reasonable* for your production code to be written as

```
clients.Where(p=>p.Identifier == "Test").Any()
```

it's not as readable, but it's fundamentally equivalent to the call to `Any` with a predicate. Your test should be able what the production code achieves, not the *exact* steps it takes to achieve it.

Comment: okay thanks for your answer. Now i see the problem with substituting the call. But how should i set up the Test correctly. Should i define an additional interface for `IDbSet<T>` with an `ExistsIdentifier(string)` method to encapsulate the linq-queries and change my Test method to work against the new interface and substitute a call to `ExistsIdentifier(string)`?

Comment: @Jehof: Well that's one option - or you could use an in-memory database, as I mentioned.

Comment: I will take a look at in-memory databases for unit tests. Thank you so far.